# Spring MVC + Maven + JBoss: can't deploy (The application must supply JDBC connections)

Tags: postgresql, maven, spring-mvc, jpa, jboss7.x

I'm currently trying to setup a Spring MVC 3.1.1 project using Maven and deploying on JBoss 7.1.1.
I have tried a few tutorials but I couldn't finish any as at some point I would get stuck with something that was assumed in the tutorial and nonexistent in my setup.

My second try was to create a "Spring MVC Project" using eclipse and copy/paste the configuration files from a working Spring MVC project to my new one but so far no good.

I created my whole domain using JPA and now that I try to deploy I get this exception: `Schema export unsuccessful: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections.`

I found many forum posts etc with people having the same issue but none of the proposed solutions suits my problem. Postgresql driver is well defined in maven dependencies and is in the build path.

Here is the main/src/resources/META-INF/**persistence.xml** file:

```
<persistence-unit name="root">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.macoloc.domain.Colocation</class>
    <class>com.macoloc.domain.Invitation</class>
    <class>com.macoloc.domain.Key</class>
    <class>com.macoloc.domain.Message</class>
    <class>com.macoloc.domain.MessageSeenBy</class>
    <class>com.macoloc.domain.Payment</class>
    <class>com.macoloc.domain.PaymentParticipation</class>
    <class>com.macoloc.domain.Ping</class>
    <class>com.macoloc.domain.Subtask</class>
    <class>com.macoloc.domain.Task</class>
    <class>com.macoloc.domain.TaskOrder</class>
    <class>com.macoloc.domain.User</class>
    <class>com.macoloc.domain.Versionable</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Here is the src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/**web.xml** file:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,/WEB-INF/spring/infrastructure/infrastructure.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is a part of src/main/resources/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/**servlet-context.xml** file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.macoloc" />

<annotation-driven />

<tx:annotation-driven />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/resources/js/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/resources/css/" />

<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

And finally the src/main/resources/WEB-INF/spring/infrastructure/**infrastructure.xml** file:

```
<context:annotation-config />

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceDirect" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSourceDirect" class="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource">
    <property name="user" value="macoloc"></property>
    <property name="password" value="macoloc"></property>
    <property name="portNumber" value="5432"></property>
    <property name="serverName" value="localhost"></property>
    <property name="databaseName" value="MaColoc"></property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

In postgres I've set the user "macoloc" to use DB "MaColoc"'s "macoloc" schema.

Note that the project I'm taking all these configuration files wasn't set by me (obviously since this one is working...). There might be some files unused? I don't know. I'm really new to this.

**Any idea where this is going wrong? Do you guys need more files?**

Thank you!

**EDIT**: here's the stacktrace:

```
16:11:21,568 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.0)
16:11:21,585 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'MaColoc.war#root'
16:11:22,205 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000231: Schema export unsuccessful: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:62) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseExporter.<init>(DatabaseExporter.java:52) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:368) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:305) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:294) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:452) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
```

And: Most weird, I noticed the tables were created in my DB... What?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You configured JPA to be initialized by Spring (using `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`), but JBoss also sees your `persistence.xml` and tries to initialize JPA on its own (as required by JPA Specification for application server environments). Obviously, it fails, because you didn't configure a data source in `persistence.xml`.

To avoid this problem Spring allows you to use different name for `persistence.xml`:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    ...
    <property name = "persistenceXmlLocation" 
        value = "classpath:/META-INF/spring-persistence.xml" />
</bean>
```

Alternatively, since Spring 3.1 you can configure JPA without `persistence.xml` at all.

**See also:**

- [`LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html)

Comment: This is working fine, but now when I'm deploying my app I'm getting a lot this message for every table (they are created tho):

13:56:22,290 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table User (id int4 not null, version int4 not null, email varchar(255) not null, firstName varchar(255) not null, lastName varchar(255) not null, password varchar(255) not null, colocation_id int4, key_id int4, primary key (id))
13:56:22,290 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-2) ERROR: syntax error near « User ».

Comment: OK nvm I only get that for User and all associations to User, I guess it's a protected word in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

There is a second way to solve this solution.  You can tell JBoss to ignore the persistence.xml.

Add the following property to the persistence.xml `<properties>`

`<property name="jboss.as.jpa.managed" value="false"/>`

This is explained in the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JPA+Reference+Guide) as the "jboss.as.jpa.managed - can be set to false to disable container managed JPA access to the persistence unit.  The default is true, which enables container managed JPA access to the persistence unit.  This is typically set to false for Seam 2.x + Spring applications. "